# I have a inline image aligned to the right in a master with one column. How to keep the image to the right with 2 cols master_

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

I have a master with only one column (A) and the picture it-s into the text frame. Now I need 2 columns but how to make the logo to stay on the right?

We found 2 solutions but are not very good:

- create an another text-frame with the width of the page and the height of the image. Then the 2 columns will start when the image's text-frame ends (the problems is that the image might have different heights. Also it implies the creation of another master page)
- put the image outside the text-frame and let it to push the text in the right col. (This is not good because the left column will start before the right column)

[image]

Comment: Does text wrap the image in A? Is there some reason you can't simply change the text wrap to "jump object"? Or even start text frames below the image?Why is creating a second master page a problem?

Comment: no, in A the image is inline (into the text-frame), therefore it pushes the content. In my second solution for 2 cols the image it's not in the text-frame and the text-wrap is set to jump object. In my second solution the 2 text-frames are starting below. Creating a new master increases complexity and I would like to keep the number of masters to minimum..

Answer (score 1):

If the picture isn't supposed to follow the text anyway, i would keep it outside of the textbox. You can resize the artbox to "catch" both columns[image]

Comment: Seems a good idea.. it's a good idea to put the image frame in the master?

Comment: If it's a logo and on every page - why not?

Comment: yes it's a logo, but only in the first page. I would like to repeat the logo, but it should be automated if possible

Answer (score 1):

If there's no wrap anyway.....

I would merely start the master text frame below the the image. Then, even if you split the text frame it will remain below the image.

[image: one text area]

[image: two columns]

One master, nothing needs to change on the master. You can split the text frame dynamically when needed and it remains in place.

Comment: how to split the text-frame dynamically and still use the the goodies of the master? if I change the height of the text-frame it will update to the height of the 2 cols?